# Drupal Form Button + "Are you sure"-Button

Tags: javascript, forms, ajax

I am trying to add an own JS function to a Drupal Core Form - think Config, Development, Clean Cache. This function basically just asks if the user is sure. Here is what I have so far:

```
Drupal.behaviors.confirm_delete = {

    attach: function (context, settings) {

         jQuery("#field-module-subsections-values input[id$='-remove-button']", context).bind('mousedown', function (ev) {

            ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();

            var followLink = window.confirm(question);

            if (followLink) {
                jQuery(this).click();
            }

            return false;

        });
    }
}
```

The problem I have is, that the function gets called before the click-event (thanks to mousedown), but the Ajax action on the button still fires. Maybe someone has a hint as to why?

Answer (score -1):

Using hook_form_alter you can implement simple popups like this using [`#attributes`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes).

```
 $form['submit']['#attributes'] => array(
  'onclick' => 'if(!confirm("Are you sure?")){return false;}',
 );
```

or

```
$form['submit']['#attributes']['onclick'] = 'if(!confirm("Are you sure?")){return false;}';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can I assign it to one certain button instead of the whole form?

Comment: Yes, just replace the 'submit' with your button.